# how to use a javascript many time on a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var newYear = document.getElementById('HF');
            alert('hehe' + newYear);
            $('#countdown').countdown({ until: newYear, format: 'DHMS', layout:
'<div id="timer">' + '<hr />' +
    '<div id="timer_days" class="timer_numbers">{dnn}</div>' +
    '<div id="timer_hours" class="timer_numbers">{hnn}</div>' +
    '<div id="timer_mins" class="timer_numbers">{mnn}</div>' +
    '<div id="timer_seconds" class="timer_numbers">{snn}</div>' +
'<div id="timer_labels">' +
    '<div id="timer_days_label" class="timer_labels">days</div>' +
    '<div id="timer_hours_label" class="timer_labels">hours</div>' +
    '<div id="timer_mins_label" class="timer_labels">mins</div>' +
    '<div id="timer_seconds_label" class="timer_labels">secs</div>' +
'</div>' +
'</div>'
            });
        });
</script>
```

How can i use this script many times on the page???I have three `listViews` ont the page so i want to use it 3 times??how can i do that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a countdown `class` instead of an `id`, so you could use the `$(".countdown")` selector instead.

Answer (score 0):

change from using  `$('#countdown').`   to using by class   `$('.countdown').`

Answer (score 0):

Give the listviews the same class, eg. .countdown and then change your JavaScript to $('.countdown').countdown(...